# Replicate application state for collaborative functionality

Tags: web-applications, redux, couchdb, state, collaboration

I am building a web application whose state shall be kept up to date and be mutable on a number of devices (web browsers, apps).
To give some idea of the application: the state consists mainly of a music playlist where clients can add tracks and vote on them. The main goal is to make it feel very 'live': changes to the state are immediately persisted and replicated, i.e. when some user adds a track to the playlist, it should immediately be visible on all devices.

I assume the application state to be a JSON document like

```
{
   "playlist" : [
       { "title" : "Lateralus", "upvotes" : 112358 },
       { "title" : "Some other song", "upvotes" : 2 }
   ]
}
```

What are some efficient strategies (replication protocols, tools) for achieving something like that?

The most trivial strategy would be to keep the application state on a central server and push the whole state to every client on every change. Of course this puts high strain on the network for a large application state, although it would probably be sufficient for a small one.

Other things I thought about include defining a set of 'actions', similar to [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) reducers. Instead of transporting the state over the network, we only transport the changes. To ensure a consistent state over all devices, we would have to make sure the same actions are applied in the same order everywhere.

Apparently CouchDB already implements a replication protocol for databases that also run in the browser. The biggest concern I have about it is that my web application has an indefinite number of application states to manage (groups of people share one application state), which results in multiple databases to be handled by the infrastructure, and that does not sound like something this was intended to do. But maybe this concern is unfounded.

Are there any best practices for a problem like this? I feel like this is not something new, as apps like Google Docs achieve something similar. Please share any thoughts about architecture patterns or even existing solutions.